# Nuxt3: How to set runtime environment variables after docker build via process.env

Tags: node.js, docker, vue.js, environment-variables, nuxt.js

My nuxt3 app works great if I build & run it locally with docker-compose and environment variables.

But when I push the built docker image to my remote production environment I'm not able to apply the production environment variables in the runtimeConfig. Probably because process.env["SECRET_KEY"] gets replaced with "the real secret key" during the build phase.

If I name environment variables NUXT_PUBLIC_XXXX / NUXT_XXXX, I'm able to update runtimeConfig even after building the image.

But as I use a PaaS Service for my production deployment, I am not in control of the variable naming. Therefore I'm unable to dynamically provide the right runtime config for my remote environment -> *I always end up with the local values which were set during the build phase on my local machine.* (see clientID in example below)

**Is there a way how to set the runtime config via process.env["custom env name"] even after the image was built?** Or do you have any other idea how to dynamically provide the runtime config? (I'd like to avoid building separate containers for each environment

Thx a lot for your inputs. Any help is highly appreciated!

```
#nuxt.config.ts
...
runtimeConfig: {

#in production ENVs are accessible under the key "VCAP_SERVICES", if key is not present the local development env is applied
clientId: process.env["VCAP_SERVICES"] ? process.env["VCAP_SERVICES"]["clientId"] : process.env["UAA_CLIENT_ID"],
secretKey: process.env["NUXT_SECRET_KEY"]

  public: {
    backendApi: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000',  // will be overridden by NUXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_API environment variable
    environment: "production", // will be overridden by NUXT_PUBLIC_ENVIRONMENT environment variable
        }
    },
```

Comment: Which PaaS Service are you using? Your env vars names are dynamically generated on each deploy on this platform?

Comment: I'm using cloud foundry. As services like a database are added to my app, a new key-value pair is added to the ENV named VCAP_SERVICES with a predefined & service specific structure (I would know how to access each value upfront e.g process.env["VCAP_SERVICES"][DatabaseServices][0][DB_User]. See https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/environment-variable.html

Comment: Maybe you're getting your env var VCPA_SERVICES as a string. You could try to parse that string as a JSON in order to get your "clientId" as you do. E.g `JSON.parse(process.env["VCAP_SERVICES"])["clientId"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to provide environment variables at runtime (after building the docker image) but only if adhere to the following requirements (see [Nuxt Docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/going-further/runtime-config/))

> Runtime config values are automatically replaced by matching environment variables at runtime. There are two key requirements.
>
> 1. Your desired variables must be defined in your nuxt.config. This ensures that arbitrary environment variables are not exposed to your application code.
> 2. Only a specially-named environment variable can override a runtime config property. That is, an uppercase environment variable starting with NUXT_ which uses _ to separate keys and case changes..

Comment: How do you inject the env and overwrite the in docker? I'm not able to achieve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75970917/nuxt3-dockerize-and-replace-env-at-a-runtime. Any help appriciated

Comment: @Vikkes: I updated the answer with a better explanation of the nuxt runtime config