# Nuxt3 dockerize and replace env at a runtime

Tags: docker, vuejs3, nuxt3

Situation:

- I have a nuxt3 app and want to dockerize it.
- Docker container will be deployed in DEV/TEST/PROD environments.
- There are some ENV VARs in .env which are declared in runtimeConfig of nuxt.config.ts as well.
- Those ENV VARs depend on DEV/TEST/PROD environments and need to be imported on a runtime [NOT BUILD] of docker

Things I tried:

- In Dockerfile I have an `ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]` which replaces ENV VARs in files .output/public/_nuxt/entry.XXXXXX.js , e.g. `sed -i 's|e.public.API_PUBLIC_URL|'\"${API_PUBLIC_URL}\"'|g' .output/public/_nuxt/entry.XXXXXX.js`
- I run `npm run build` locally and changed entry.*.js manually. After run `npm start`

Result:

- Script replacement in docker and by manual replacement with vi breaks/corrupt the app. App does not start and says that entry.xxxxx.js is broken.

Questions:

- Is it possible to adjust nuxt3 .output files after build?
- Does nuxt have some checksum of js files?
- Any other ways how to inject ENV VARs in nuxt3 docker app at runtime?

Dokerfile

```
FROM node:18-alpine3.16 as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./ .
RUN npm run build

FROM node:18-alpine3.16 as production-stage
RUN mkdir /app
COPY --from=build-stage /app/.output /app/.output
ENV NUXT_HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV NUXT_PORT=3000
COPY /entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

EXPOSE 3000
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh

```
ROOT_DIR=/app

# Replace env vars in JavaScript files
echo "Replacing env constants in JS"
for file in $ROOT_DIR/.output/public/_nuxt/entry.*.js   
do
  echo "Processing $file ...";

  sed -i 's|e.public.API_AUTH_DOMAIN|'\"${API_AUTH_DOMAIN}\"'|g' $file 
  sed -i 's|e.public.API_PROTOCOL|'\"${API_PROTOCOL}\"'|g' $file 
  sed -i 's|e.public.API_PUBLIC_URL|'\"${API_PUBLIC_URL}\"'|g' $file  

done

node "/app/.output/server/index.mjs"
```

docker entrypoint and manual replacement Error in browser
[image]

UPDATE:

I found that after changing the entry.js it's not loaded coompletly

here is end of js in browser
`,Id a` but it goes `,Id as w,bx as x,Sx as y,vx as z};`. Which means that length of my file has increased through the replacement of ENV VARS. But how is that all conflicting at all?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm setting the env variables on docker build time and inside the container, when I'm printing the envs, they are set correctly, but Nuxt is unable to retrieve them through publicRuntimeConfig

Comment: do you have NUXT_ as prefix in .env by names of your vars? and do you use useRuntimeConfig(); ?

Comment: Yes. Both of them. Managed to pass the private envs to client by adding VITE_ prefix on envs and accessing them with import.meta.vite.var

Comment: in nuxt you should use NUXT_ https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/going-further/runtime-config "Only a specially-named environment variable can override a runtime config property. That is, an uppercase environment variable starting with NUXT_ which uses _ to separate keys and case changes."

Comment: @Vikkes Laurentiu has NUXT prefix for variables, but it still doesnt work. I have exactly the same poblem. Env is set, but nuxt does not read it in runtime when is dockerized, see -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76978604/runtime-loading-operating-system-variable-in-nuxt-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nuxt will already apply ENV variables when set via `runtimeConfig`.

When you e.g. set `runtimeConfig.apiUrl`, the env variable would be `NUXT_API_URL`.

More [in the docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/migration/runtime-config#runtime-config).